# Do I need to call the offAuth Method on logging out?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a function which was previously working to store user details in the User node in my Firebase database. However upon trying it today it is now returning an error message saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
```

The code I have written simply stores the auth.uid as a child of user and then within that node it stores all data of that user. As of Friday this worked for a few users but now it is now producing the above error message.

To fix this do I need to call the offAuth method upon logging out? If so, How would I go about this?

My code so far is below.

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
    ref.child('user').child(authData.uid).set(authData).then(function(auth) {
        console.log('Data Saved Successfully!');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onAuth()` method is called whenever the authentication state of the user changes. This means that it is called both when the user is authenticated and when they get unauthenticated. In the latter case, the `authData` argument will be `null` and you have to handle that in your code.

From the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication):

Use the onAuth() method to listen for changes in user authentication state.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
});
```

You're missing that `if` in your code.

Comment: Perfect... Feel pretty stupid for missing that. Thanks.